# INSERT INTO with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm trying myself in mysql now, but there is a problem. I can't insert values to my table. 
Can you help me ? 
Here is my code:

```
$con=mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','taxon');

$query='INSERT INTO order (phone, pointA, pointB)
VALUES ("43532", "daram", "pampam")';

$result= mysql_query($query, $con);
echo $result;
```

database: taxon
table name : order
table values: id(A_I), phone, pointA, pointB

Comment: Order is a reserved word,use back ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db("taxon");
 ..
 mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: This one saved my ass!
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

You're missing quotes around your string values in your query, plus `order` is a reserved word which need to be wrapped in backticks:

```
$query='INSERT INTO `order` (phone, pointA, pointB)
 VALUES (43532, hye, moe)';
```

should be

```
$query="INSERT INTO `order` (phone, pointA, pointB)
 VALUES (43532, 'hye', 'moe')";
```

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: i tried with them and without, result is the same

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I think it may be the `order` thing John. I edited your answer.

Comment: NO errors at all.
But $con = Resource id #2
And $result is empty.
with this `order` nothing changed

Comment: @JohnConde . . . The query does have quotes around the string variables, because MySQL allows double quotes to be used for quoting strings (bad idea but I didn't design the language).  The problem is the `order`.

Comment: I fixed another typo John. You had `poinA` instead of `pointA`

Comment: @Animus Reload John's answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was a copy and paste error! I swear!

Comment: I noticed pointA right after posting.
here is how query looks like now

$query="INSERT INTO `order` (phone, pointA, pointB)
VALUES ('43532', 'hye', 'moe')";

and the order is in quotes

Comment: Hehehe I believe you John ;-)